# How to use pandas-gbq with BigQuery Storage API within AI platform training?

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, gcp-ai-platform-training

I'm submitting a training job to the GCP AI platform training service. My training dataset (around 40M rows on a BigQuery table in the same GCP project) needs to be preprocessed at the beginning of the training job as a pandas dataframe, so I tried both the solutions proposed by the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration#using_the_to_download_large_results):

- pandas_gbq API: `pd.read_gbq(query, project_id=PROJECT, dialect='standard', use_bqstorage_api=True)`
- google-cloud-bigquery API: `client.query(query).to_dataframe(bqstorage_client=bqstorage_client)`

Both methods work on a AI platform notebook VM, downloading the whole 40M rows dataset as a pandas dataframe in few minutes. I'm struggling to replicate the same procedure on the AI platform training server (that runs on a n1-highmem-16 machine). In the case of pandas-gbq API I obtain a permission denied error:

`google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 request failed: the user does not have bigquery.readsessions.create' permission for 'projects/acn-c4-crmdataplatform-dev'`

In the case of the google-cloud-bigquery API there are no errors.

Here is the list of the required package that I, as suggested by the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/packaging-trainer#adding_standard_pypi_dependencies), pass to the AI platform training job with a setup.py file in the trainer package:

- tensorflow==2.1.0
- numpy==1.18.2
- pandas==1.0.3
- google-api-core==1.17.0
- google-cloud-core==1.3.0
- pyarrow==0.16.0
- pandas-gbq==0.13.1
- google-cloud-bigquery-storage==0.8.0
- google-cloud-bigquery==1.24.0

Answer (score 2):

You have to do 2 things:

- First, check that service account `service-<PROJECT_NUMBER>@cloud-ml.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com` exist and has the `Cloud ML Service Agent` role. If not, add it manually (you don't have to create it!)
- Grant this service account the permission to query your BigQuery dataset.